# Branch.io app indexing is not searching app via google app

Tags: android, branch.io

I have setup following code for app indexing using Branch.io

```
   BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject = new BranchUniversalObject()
                .setCanonicalIdentifier("testing/")
                .setCanonicalUrl("testing") // optional
                .setTitle("irctc")
                .setContentDescription("my tetsing ")
                .setContentImageUrl("http://example.com/xyz")
                .setContentIndexingMode(BranchUniversalObject.CONTENT_INDEX_MODE.PUBLIC)
                .addContentMetadata("property1", "x")
                .addContentMetadata("property2", "y");

branchUniversalObject.listOnGoogleSearch(this);
```

**Manifest**

```
        <data
            android:host="open"
            android:scheme="testing"  />
```

**I also have enabled in Branch dashboard page:-**

Automatic sitemap generation (for Google App Indexing)

But the concern is google app is not searching my app when is search via keyword "testing".

Can anyone tell me where i am mistaken. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: while theoretically possible, this is not likely to produce results. The steps you've taken will **submit** this piece of content to Google for indexing (though there is a delay of up to 24 hours before that submission happens on the Branch end). Unfortunately this is simply a submission and not any sort of guarantee that Google will actually **do anything** with what you have submitted.

The algorithms Google uses for indexing and ranking are not public, so even if the submission is successful, it's very possible that a piece of content like what you have configured above would be ignored as not valuable.

You can read more about the Branch App Indexing implementation on [this documentation page](https://dev.branch.io/features/google-app-indexing/guide/android/)